# Flask: Static files in subdirectories

Tags: python, flask, fastcgi

In my flask template file I include a css file (I ommited the boilerplate) like this:

`url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css')`

This renders to `/static/css/bootstrap.css` which means (because of leading slash) it is interpreted as `domain.com/static/css/boostrap.css`. Unfortunately the actual `static` folder is located a subdirectory: `domain.com/projects/test/static/`

**Environment specifics:**

My fcgi file located in the `~/fcgi-bin` folder (host specific i guess):

```
$ cat ~/fcgi-bin/test.fcgi
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/abcc/html/projects/test")

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from app import app

class ScriptNameStripper(object):
   def __init__(self, app):
       self.app = app

   def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
       environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
       return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = ScriptNameStripper(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

and my .htaccess located in domain.com/projects/test/

```
$ cat .htaccess 
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
       SetHandler fcgid-script
       Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
   </Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fcgi-bin/test.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

To sum it up I want `url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css')` to return `static/css/bootstrap.css` instead of `/static/css/bootstrap.css`

### EDIT #1

I have noticed this happens also on normal url_for calls not for static files like url_for('about').

### EDIT #2

I have written a [quickstart-app](https://github.com/JonasGroeger/flask-uberspace-quickstart) and [a blog post](http://jonasgroeger.de/projekte/blog/projekt-flask-auf-dem-hoster-uberspace-blitzschnell-mit-hubschen-urls-aufsetzen/) about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dont set the script name to a blank string, try setting it to '/projects/test'. By setting SCRIPT_NAME to a blank string the application thinks its running on the root of the domain, so routes generated by url_for will start there. With a script name of '/projects/test', `url_for('static', filename='/foo/bar.css')` will return '/projects/test/static/foo/bar.css'

If you genuinely want your apps static media served on a different endpoint then you'll just have to roll it yourself, something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from os.path import join

app = Flask(__name__)

def url_for_static(filename):
    root = app.config.get('STATIC_ROOT', '')
    return join(root, filename)
```

Comment: you can get the static folder path with: ```url_for('static', filename='')```